# What does the "scale" parameter in scipy.stats.t.std() stand for?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

My goal is, to find the standard deviation of a dataset with a supposed t-distribution to calculate the survival function given a quantile.
As the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html) of scipy.stats is very counter intuitive to me, I tried several things and ended up with the implementation below. (Note: the numerated variables only demonstrate, that there are different results. My goal is to end up with only one result each!)

```
import scipy

df, loc, scale = scipy.stats.t.fit(data, fdf=len(data)-1)
std1 = scipy.stats.t.std(df=df, loc=loc, scale=scale)
std2 = scipy.stats.t.std(df=df, loc=loc)

res1 = scipy.stats.sf(some_x, df, loc, scale)
res2 = scipy.stats.sf(some_x, df, loc, std1)
res3 = scipy.stats.sf(some_x, df, loc, std2)
```

I encountered that, `loc` equals the stats.t.mean() function, when given the values from the fit-function. But `scale` does not equal stats.t.std(). Hence the `std1` and `std2` are different and not equal to `scale`.
I can only find sources for the normal distribution, where it's stated that scale equals std.
How should I use the functions above appropriatly?

Any help or suggestions for editing the question would be much appreciated :)
Code on and stay healthy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Student's T distribution is not supposed to be shifted or scaled, it's used as a standard distribution with mean=0, usually to test the difference between two means of normally distributed populations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution.

Given a sample with n observation and the Student's T distribution with v=n-1 degrees of freedom, the standard deviation is sqrt(v / (v-2)).

You can check in `scipy` that this is true

```
n = 11
v = n - 1
dist = sps.t(df=v)

# standard deviation
# from scipy distribution
print(dist.std())            # will return 1.118033988749895
# standard deviation
# from theory
print(np.sqrt(v / (v - 2)))  # will return 1.118033988749895
```